# Access sharepoint files on behalf of a guest user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to access files that are shared with a B2B guest user in Sharepoint Online. I have added the user in Azure AD, and I have given them access to certain files and folders in a sharepoint site. They can access this through the web portal, but when I log in as them via the graph API, the files do not appear.

When I execute this code as an Azure AD (non-guest) user, it runs OK and returns the sites I have access to:

```
var sites = await _graphClient.Sites.Request(new List<QueryOption>()
                                    {
                                        new QueryOption("search", "")
                                    }).GetAsync();
```

However, when I log in as a guest user, I get this error:

> ServiceException: Code: itemNotFound Message: Item not found

Is there some sort of limitation for guest users? How can I see all files that are shared with this user?

Answer (score 1):

So it appears that it is possible in a slightly more complicated way. Since we cannot use search, it means that we have to keep a list of all sharepoint sites a (guest) user is registered to.

I noticed that `var sites = await _graphClient.Sites.Request().GetAsync();` does not return an error, but instead gives you an empty array.

First, we need to know the Sharepoint site ID. The `Sites` resource has a method called `GetByPath`. This allows us to retrieve the site data:

```
var site = await _graphClient.Sites.GetByPath("/sites/Contoso-Customer1",
                      "contoso.sharepoint.com").Request().GetAsync();
```

The first argument is the site url and the second argument is the site domain. The example above shows the values for https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Contoso-Customer1.

Now we can get the site ID and list the drives. For the sake of brevity, I have omitted a couple of null checks in the examples here.
The following line will get us the drives:

```
var drives = await _graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Drives.Request().GetAsync();
```

I assume there is one drive. Retrieving the drive ID is then as simple as `var driveId = drives.First().Id`

Then we need the ID of the list. The list contains the files and folders.

```
var list = await _graphClient.Sites[site.Id]
                             .Drives[driveId]
                             .List
                             .Request()
                             .GetAsync();
```

(edit: we can also bypass the drive query and get the lists directly: `var lists = await _graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists.Request().GetAsync();` . And then the list ID is `lists.First().Id`)

Next we can retrieve all items in the list:

```
var listContent = await _graphClient.Sites[site.Id]
                               .Lists[list.Id]
                               .Items
                               .Request()
                               .GetAsync();
```

And now we can get all detailed file info. For this example, I only retrieve the file names:

```
 List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
 foreach (var item in listContent)
 {
     var file = await _graphClient.Sites[site.Id].Lists[list.Id].Items[item.Id].DriveItem.Request().GetAsync();
     fileNames.Add(file?.Name);
 }
```

Trying to directly get the file data does not work, because some properties are null:

```
listContent?.Select(x => new
            {
                x.Id, // id of item in the list
                x.Name, // null
                x.ContentType,
                DriveItemName = x.DriveItem?.Name, // null
                x.WebUrl, // exact url to file
            }),
```

(the `_graphClient` variable is based on the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core))

Comment: Do you know why external/guest users are not allowed to search? Is there any official documentation that says this or did you just experience this limitation yourself?